# Pyspark: store dataframe as JSON in MySQL table column

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe which needs to be stored in JSON format in MYSQL table as a column value. (along with other string type values in their respective column)

Something similar to this:

| column 1 | column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| val 1 | [{"name":"Peter G", "age":44, "city":"Quahog"}, {"name":"John G", "age":30, "city":"Quahog"}, {...}, ...] |
| val 1 | [{"name":"Stewie G", "age":3, "city":"Quahog"}, {"name":"Ron G", "age":41, "city":"Quahog"}, {...}, ...] |
| ... | ... |

Here `[{"name":"Peter G", "age":44, "city":"Quahog"}, {"name":"John G", "age":30, "city":"Quahog"}, {...}, ...]`  is the result of one dataframe stored as *list of dict*

I can do:

```
str(dataframe_object.toJSON().collect())
```

and then store it to mysql table column, but this would mean loading the entire data in memory, before storing it in mysql table. Is there better/optimal way to achieve this i.e. without using `collect()`?

Comment: If you are using *MySQL 5.7* or greater then you need to just store it in the column with type `json`

Comment: Hi @SuyogShimpi, yes, but how do I do it without using ```df.toJSON().collect()```, as I don't have a json object, but a pyspark dataframe

Comment: Have you try `spark.write.jdbc` http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.jdbc ?

Comment: Hi @pltc, I need dataframe to be stored as JSON. I can store dataframe directly using ```spark.write.jdbc```, but how do I convert dataframe to json before writing to mysql?

Comment: hm, why do you have to convert it to JSON before writing? Is there any specific reason? And by converting you meant to get the entire dataframe into a single string variable?

Comment: I don't necessarily need it in single variable (that would cause memory issues for large data), I just want to store dataframe in mysql table's column in json format, without being open for potential memory related issues (somethig like this ```{"name":"Peter G", "age":44, "city":"Quahog"}```)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can convert your StructType column into JSON string, then using `spark.write.jdbc` to write to MySQL. As long as [your MySQL table has that column as JSON type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html#json-values), you should be all set.

```py
# My sample data
{
    "c1": "val1",
    "c2": [
        { "name": "N1", "age": 100 },
        { "name": "N2", "age": 101 }
    ]
}

from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T

schema = T.StructType([
    T.StructField('c1', T.StringType()),
    T.StructField('c2', T.ArrayType(T.StructType([
        T.StructField('name', T.StringType()),
        T.StructField('age', T.IntegerType())
    ])))
])

df = spark.read.json('a.json', schema=schema, multiLine=True)
df.show(10, False)
df.printSchema()

+----+----------------------+
|c1  |c2                    |
+----+----------------------+
|val1|[{N1, 100}, {N2, 101}]|
+----+----------------------+

root
 |-- c1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- c2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- age: integer (nullable = true)

df.withColumn('j', F.to_json('c2')).show(10, False)
+----+----------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
|c1  |c2                    |j                                                |
+----+----------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
|val1|[{N1, 100}, {N2, 101}]|[{"name":"N1","age":100},{"name":"N2","age":101}]|
+----+----------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

EDIT #1:

```py
# My sample data
{
    "c1": "val1",
    "c2": "[{ \"name\": \"N1\", \"age\": 100 },{ \"name\": \"N2\", \"age\": 101 }]"
}

from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T

df = spark.read.json('a.json', multiLine=True)
df.show(10, False)
df.printSchema()

+----+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|c1  |c2                                                         |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|val1|[{ "name": "N1", "age": 100 },{ "name": "N2", "age": 101 }]|
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------+

root
 |-- c1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- c2: string (nullable = true)

schema = T.ArrayType(T.StructType([
    T.StructField('name', T.StringType()),
    T.StructField('age', T.IntegerType())
]))

df2 = df.withColumn('j', F.from_json('c2', schema))
df2.show(10, False)
df2.printSchema()

+----+-----------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
|c1  |c2                                                         |j                     |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
|val1|[{ "name": "N1", "age": 100 },{ "name": "N2", "age": 101 }]|[{N1, 100}, {N2, 101}]|
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+

root
 |-- c1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- c2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- j: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- age: integer (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Hi @pltc, in you solution, column c2 already has data in json format, but in my scenario, I have a dataframe with column c1 and c2 and they don't have json data, but string type values and I need all rows in that dataframe converted to list of dict. E.g; ```[{'c1': 'row1_val1', 'c2': 'row1_val2' }, {'c2': 'row2_val1', 'c2': 'row2_val2' }, ...]```

Comment: @ShubhamKadam, in that case, it's something similar, you just need to define the JSON schema for `c2`, then convert that `c2` to JSON object with `from_json`. Check my edited answer